# jQuery object .sort() not sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list by it's value but I can't figure out why it doesn't work once I changed it.

The nothing is sorted once I change the a and b part to ipArray[a/b.value].

I can confirm that all the option values exists in the ipArray as I'm able to get those values by using `selectList.each(function(){
    alert( ipArray[$(this).val()].ipAdd)
)`

```
ipArray is an array that has objects of this format

{
     ipAdd : "",
     network : ""
}

id = id of the entry
eg. ipArray[id] = { ip : "1.2.3.4", network: "test network"};


//    Example
var id = $("#list");
var selectList = $("option", id );

selectList.sort(function (a, b) {

    a = a.value;
    b = b.value;

    // Doesn't work. Would like to sort by network name then by ip address
    //a = ipArray[a.value].ipAdd;
    //b = ipArray[b.value].ipAdd;

    return a - b;
});

id.html(selectList);
```

Edit:

Created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bme4rv6o/12/
With the expected output

Comment: Can you provide a bigger sample data. What is to be expected in  the selectList? You're sample object is different from the object you provide in the example.

Comment: Added fiddle with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `a.value` is a string. Parse it to int and subtract 1 from it to then use the result as the index.

Finally, use `localeCompare` to sort strings, instead of subtracting.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bme4rv6o/13/

Also, you'll probably need to add more logic to sort function to handle a tie (EG, when both `a` and `b` are equal, return an IP comparison (which would also need proper parse for each token separated by the dots)).

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting using a property `value` which doesn't even exists in the `object`

```
selectList.sort(function (a, b) {

     var _network = a.network.localCompare(b.network);
     var _ip  = a.ip.localCompare(b.ip);

     // Will first check network, if equal will then check IP
     return (_network==0?_ip:_network);    

});
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. As the selectList only has the index not the object itself, so I cant just .ip or .network it.

Comment: Please paste your selectList in the original post.

Comment: Created a fiddle, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply one line of code:

It evaluates the first part and if the network is the same, then the other part is evaluated.

```
selectList.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.network.localeCompare(b.network) || a.ipAdd.localeCompare(b.ipAdd);
});
```

The algorithm is working fine, see below. But your `selectList` does contain an object, whicht is not sortable like you would like.

```js
var ipArray = [];

function add(ip, network) {
    ipArray.push({ ip: ip, network: network });
}

add("1.1.1.1", "A");
add("2.2.2.2", "B");
add("3.3.3.3", "D");
add("4.4.4.4", "C");
add("5.5.5.5", "A");

ipArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.network.localeCompare(b.network) || a.ip.localeCompare(b.ip);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ipArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. As the selectList only has the index not the object itself, so I cant just .ip or .network it.

Comment: @Tim, your object `selectList` is not sortable.

Comment: So it's not possible within the sort method to use the A and B value to get the object from the array?

Comment: please write `alert(JSON.stringify(selectList, 0, 4));` in function a(). the reference for the sorting data should be different.